# How to make image look more greyish

Tags: python, image

I have the follwoing image:

[image]

Anyhow I want to make it look more grey-like:

[image]

I tried changing the contrast and brightness, but that didn't seem to work. Any other solution?

Comment: show us some code, how do you read the file, what have you tried codewise...

Comment: Do you want to convert it to grayscale or simply desaturate it?

Comment: @martineau whichever helps achieve the desired image. grayscale didn't work, code is mentioned in one of the solutions

Comment: To desaturate it, convert it to HSV colorspace and reduce S, then convert it back to original colorspace (probably RGB).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using OpenCV :

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread(Your Image Path)

gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

Output: (Image has no Background...so it is displayed in black)

[image]

Or Pillow:

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open('image.png').convert('LA')
img.save('greyscale.png')
```

Comment: It just makes it look even whiter

Comment: what do you expect... the image has no background, is mostly white and the only colours are very light, soo you get an image with a lot of whites and light greys...

Comment: the wire looks whiter. It doesn't look more grey

Comment: the wire itself is white in the original...it is not getting whiter, it may seem like it is because of the strong contrast to the black background, but white stays white in this cv2-manipulation

Comment: Can't we change color of image? pixel values

Comment: sure, but that is something different than transforming a colour image into gray values... then you have to modify the RGB-Values manually I guess, never done something like that.